# Android geofencing doesn't working with dynamically geofences loaded (volley request)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

I'm trying to load a geofences dynamically from an api but I have a problem. 
When I load static data into my app (hard-coded for example) everything goes well (geofence triggered fastly) but If I try to load data from a remote server the geofence action doesn't trigger anymore. I use Volley to handle request.

onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Empty list for storing geofences.
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

    // Initially set the PendingIntent used in addGeofences() and removeGeofences() to null.
    mGeofencePendingIntent = null;

    geofencePointsRequest(this, null, null);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
```

Volley request to retrieve data

```
public void geofencePointsRequest(final Context context, Map<String,String> params, final ProgressDialog pDialog){
    webService = new WebService();

    CustomArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new CustomArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            WebServiceUrl.POINTS,
            params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    ArrayList<Point> points = webService.getPoints(response);
                    populateGeofenceList(points);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String errorHandler = webService.getError(error);
                    int status = (error.networkResponse.statusCode != 0) ? error.networkResponse.statusCode : 0;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Code : " + status + " - Error : " + errorHandler, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return webService.getHeaders();
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue("pointsRequest", jsonObjReq);
}
```

Build GoogleApiClient

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

On connected I load geofences

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    addGeofencesOnLoad();
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

public void addGeofencesOnLoad() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
}
```

I create a list of geofences (from data parsed)

```
public void populateGeofenceList(ArrayList<Point> points) {
    for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(pins.get(i).getShortId())
                .setCircularRegion(
                        points.get(i).getLocation().getCoordinates().latitude,
                        points.get(i).getLocation().getCoordinates().longitude,
                        points.get(i).getLocation().getRadius()
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .build());
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have refactored buildGoogleApiClient position in code but the problem is always that it doesn't fire notification...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not initializing Google Api Client, **buildGoogleApiClient()** method doesn't execute until **populateGeofenceList** is called and this is not done if you haven't connect to the Google Api Client.

So your problem might be Google Api Client is null so is not connecting. Check here:

```
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i removed this but not he issue :( With Constants works...with dynamic data no :-(

Comment: What was the problem with the geofence ids?

Comment: Oh i see so i guess the last one was overwriting  the previous one.

Comment: No, the problem was that i had many geofences, some with the same ids...(p.e. ids were 1,2,3,1,4,3..., this cause an issue).